# Used Gparted to shrink a windows partition, can I restore it?

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, windows, mount, ntfs

Firstly, now I really understand how stupid it is to shrink a NTFS Windows 7 partition with Gparted when the windows partition manager wont let me shrink as much as I want but... too late!

So, I have Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows 7 on my old laptop. A 120 GB disk, which was partitioned in two disk of 60GB, later I decided to install Ubuntu and shrinked the second Windows partition by 15(not really sure) GB for the Ubuntu. Everything worked well for a year but it was obvious that I would need more space for the Ubuntu. Yesterday, I was ready for the process, to shrink my half-empty windows partition (the one that shrinked the first time, not the boot one) and started the windows partition manager, but it allowed me to shrink only 13GB when the free was 30 GB. So I said "Damn it, Gparted will do the work" and shrinked 23-4 GB with it...big mistake. The partition got broken. 
Here is what Gparted [shows](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88292666/Screenshot%20from%202013-12-15%2019:14:01.png) and the error is [this.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88292666/Screenshot%20from%202013-12-15%2019:22:05.png) Chkdsk in windows can't check the disk and wants me to format it. All the linux ntfs tools that I tried show the exact same error(ntfsfix /dev/sda5, ntfs-3g -o force,rw /dev/sda5 /media/windows).
Here it the output for "fdisk -lu"

```
Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa8d32665

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   117210239    58605088+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       117210301   234246143    58517921+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       117210303   155189247    18989472+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       204316672   231659519    13671424   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       231661568   234246143     1292288   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

And from the "parted /dev/sda unit s print"

```
Model: ATA ST9120822AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 234441648s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start       End         Size        Type      File system     Flags
 1      63s         117210239s  117210177s  primary   ntfs            boot
 2      117210301s  234246143s  117035843s  extended                  lba
 5      117210303s  155189247s  37978945s   logical   ntfs
 6      204316672s  231659519s  27342848s   logical   ext4
 7      231661568s  234246143s  2584576s    logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

I would be very thankful if there is a way to recover the data from the partition (its not really important but would be happy to save it), and more important to explain me what to do from now so I can have what I want, working: Primary Windows Partition(obiously), smaller second windows partition, larger linux partition. Thank you in advance, I'm here to provide any information needed :)

Comment: GParted offers a "data recue" function... (Menu Drive->Try rescue or sth.)

Comment: Cant recover anything, it says it cant be mounted or smth similar, damn it :(

Comment: You might try [photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to try to recover files.  Note that it recovers much more than just pictures.